# How Run shiny with cloud9-IDE

Tags: shiny, cloud9-ide, rstudio-server

I follow all steps by install shiny server that is the url https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/

All work good without problems, but when I try to run with the port 3838, doen`t work.

I try several ways

the url of my install is https://corona-shiny-maestrocorona.c9users.io:3838/

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud9 only supports ports 8080, 8081 and 8082, so you will have to listen on 0.0.0.0 and one of these ports. The url to server listening on port 8080 doesn't need a port suffix in the url (like so: `https://corona-shiny-maestrocorona.c9users.io/`), but to access servers listening on 8081 and 8082, you'll need to affix the port (like so: `https://corona-shiny-maestrocorona.c9users.io:8081/`).